# Teradata dynamic SQL getting code from another table

Tags: teradata

I am trying to recreate a query that uses a subquery in the left join to get the value of a KPI. I am trying to store that subquery in another table as a string and use dynamic sql to retrieve that string code and insert it into the left join, but I am getting an error:

```
[5526] SPL2010:E(L27), Variable of CHARACTER type expected in PREPARE or EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement.
```

Here is the procedure I am trying to create. In the variable metric_code, the column SQL is a string that contains the sql code.

```
Create PROCEDURE dyn_sql_test()
BEGIN

        DECLARE metric_code VARCHAR(5000);
        
        Set metric_code = (Select SQL_CODE from  mytable_with_Sql_code where ID=1234);

                BEGIN
                        set get_value='
                        SELECT 
                            e.*
                            ,a.value    
                        FROM  Metric_table AS e  

                        LEFT JOIN ('||metric_code||') a
                        on e.id=a.id

                        WHERE e.ID = 1234;';
                        
                        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE get_value;
                    
                END;
  END;
```

In case it helps, the string I am retrieving for SQL_CODE, which used to go in the Left Join as a subquery looks something like this:

```
sel id,type,values 
from my_values_table 
where type='kpi'
```

Comment: You didn't DECLARE get_value. But you can't EXECUTE IMMEDIATE a SELECT statement either. You need to DECLARE CURSOR FOR statement_name, PREPARE statement_name FROM  the_SQL_string, OPEN the cursor and FETCH the result.

Comment: @Fred, That was it!! I missed declaring get_value. what a dummy. And you are also right about the execute immediate. Is that only if I want to return the values? my final goal is not to display the values but to insert them into a different table. would I be able to execute immediate in that case?

Comment: Yes, a statement that does not potentially return data, like INSERT / SELECT, should be fine in EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.